# Ubuntu LAN connection not working

Tags: networking, lan

Good morning.

My internet connection on Ubuntu is not working. I remember when I installed Ubuntu it wasn't working as well, after lots of struggling I finally got it working. But last weekend I had to pull out the LAN cable out of my PC and I've got it back in now. Unfortunately my internet connection isn't working anymore now.

It does work on Windows 7 (dual boot).

I did these commands to show you the output:

```
$ sudo ethtool eth0

Settings for eth0:
Cannot get device settings: No such device
Cannot get wake-on-lan settings: No such device
Cannot get message level: No such device
Cannot get link status: No such device
No data available
```

-

```
$ ifconfig

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:2942 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2942 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:247513 (247.5 KB)  TX bytes:247513 (247.5 KB)
```

-

```
$ lspci -nn | grep Ethernet

02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 06)
```

**EDIT after StallionSA comment**

I tried your first commands, without result:

```
$ sudo ip link set dev eth0 down
Cannot find device "eth0"

$ sudo dhclient eth0
Cannot find device "eth0"

$ sudo ip addr add 192.168.1.14/24 dev eth0
Cannot find device "eth0"

$ sudo ip link set dev eth0 up
Cannot find device "eth0"

$ sudo ip route add default via 192.168.1.1
RTNETLINK answers: Network is unreachable
```

After that, I tried both to edit the interfaces file, trying a dynamic and static IP both without result:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart

[....] Restarting networking (via systemctl): networking.serviceJob for networking.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status networking.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
 failed!
```

This was in the interfaces file before I edited it:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

**EDIT 2**

This command works for the internet connection:

```
sudo modprobe r8169 && dmesg | grep r816
```

I have to re-enter the command each time I reboot, how could I fix this?

Comment: Please post the output of ipconfig -a to show all network devices as ipconfig only shows managed devices. Thanks.

Comment: The usual driver for your device is `r8169`. Let's load it and look for clues in the log: `sudo modprobe r8169 && dmesg | grep r816` Please edit your question to add the result. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 Thank you! This did it for me.

Comment: @chili555 I have to re-enter the command each time I reboot. Do you know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To automate loading the driver, open a terminal and do:

```
sudo -i
echo r8169  >>  /etc/modules
exit
```

You should be all set. If this is ineffective, check to see if the module is blacklisted:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

Use nano or kate or leafpad if you don't have the text editor gedit. Check to see if there is a line blacklisting r8169. If so remove it. Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

Also, check to see if there is any specific file blacklisting it:

```
ls /etc/modprobe.d
```

If you find such a file, remove it. Reboot and tell us if it is working.

Comment: Nope doesn't fix it, still have to do it manually.

Comment: Please see my edit above.

Comment: Thank you! It was indeed blacklisted and after removal everything works fine. If I may ask, how could it have been blacklisted in the first place?

Comment: It isn't normally blacklisted unless someone specifically did so, for example, to try a different driver.

Answer (score 0):

Taken form the following ubuntu documentation.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkConfigurationCommandLine/Automatic

Configuring an interface

Word of wisdom
We will use eth0 in this example, your interface can be named differently, see Finding your network interface.
If you have disabled the either wicd or the network manager you probably don't have a network connection anymore. Connect via a regular UTP cable to your router, and assuming you have DHCP enabled do the following:

`sudo ip link set dev eth0 down`

`sudo dhclient eth0`

This will bring your eth0 up by using DHCP. Your network is now configured (for the time being).

If you don't have DHCP enabled configure your network by issueing the commands below, the gateway address is the IP address of your router. And your IP should be in the same range as the router is.

`sudo ip addr add 192.168.1.14/24 dev eth0`

`sudo ip link set dev eth0 up`

`sudo ip route add default via 192.168.1.1`

These commands configure your interface but these changes will not survive a reboot, since the information is not stored anyhwere. This is where the interfaces file comes in handy. To configure a interface permanently you'll need to edit the interfaces file, /etc/network/interfaces.

`sudo vi /etc/network/interfaces`

### To configure a dynamic IP address

auto eth0

iface eth0 inet dhcp

### Or configure a static IP

auto eth0

iface eth0 inet static

address 192.168.1.14

gateway 192.168.1.1

netmask 255.255.255.0

network 192.168.1.0

broadcast 192.168.1.255

For these settings to take effect you need to restart your networking services.

`sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart`

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I tried your solutions without luck, I edited my post with the results.